# Unterminated String Literal in JQuery

Tags: jquery, cakephp

I have used cakePhp Form->input to create a Dropdown box inside JQuery using

```
 $('<?php echo $form->input($r['Attribute']['label'], array('name'=>$r['Attribute']['label'],'options'=>array(1,2,3)));?>').appendTo("#main #EntrySubmit");
```

But its showing me the error as Unterminated String literal...Why so???

Comment: $("selector").appendTo("selector2") - append to expects a set of elements, that's been selected. You try to put html code instead of selector - that's why the errors. See my edited answer for more.

Comment: there's nothing wrong with the `appendTo()` part of the code. See the docs: http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/appendTo

Answer (score 5):

I think you might be having a problem if your PHP is outputting any line breaks. eg:

```
// BAD:
$('<div class="input select"><label for="Gender">
    Gender</label>').appendTo(...)

// GOOD:
$('<div class="input select"><label for="Gender">Gender</label>').appendTo(...)
```

If this is the case, replace the linebreaks with a space or with nothing:

```
// change from this:
$('<?php echo $form->input("blah", ...); ?>').appendTo(...)

// to this:
$('<?php echo str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), "", $form->input("blah", ...)); ?>')
    .appendTo(...)
```

... or if you want to keep the new lines, you'll need to escape them with a slash.

```
// this gives "Unterminated string literal"    
var x = 'abc
def';

// this gives you "abcdef"
var x = 'abc\
def';
```

Answer (score -1):

You probably need to escape the single quotes in the `$form` output with `addslashes()`.

--edit2

`addcslashesh()` adds the escaping char `\` to specified characters. You have single quotes in your JS code, that's why you need to escape the existing single quotes in your php ouput.

```
$("#main #EntrySubmit").append('
<?php 
echo addcslashes(
   $form->input($r['Attribute']['label'], 
                array('name'=>$r['Attribute']['label'],
                      'options'=>array(1,2,3))
                ),
   "'"
   );
?>
');
```

Comment: can give brief me about addslashes()

Comment: Still i am geeting the Error as  Unterminated String literal  $('

Comment: what does your php output looks like?

Comment: if addcslashes is used it shows me the error as   
    $('
                      <div class="input select"><label for="Gender">Gender</label><select name="Gender" id="Gender">
<option value="0">1</option>
<option value="1">2</option>
<option value="2">3</option>
</select></div>                      ').appendTo("#main #EntrySubmit");

Comment: with unterminated String literal $('

Comment: Ah, ok, I see it now, you should use $("#main #EntrySubmit").append('
<?php 
echo addcslashes(
   $form->input($r['Attribute']['label'], 
                array('name'=>$r['Attribute']['label'],
                      'options'=>array(1,2,3))
                ),
   "'"
   );
?>
');

Comment: appendTo actually expects a dom-element and you haven't selected one but you want to create one.

Comment: @stefita - firstly, there's no single quotes in his output. secondly, `appendTo()` takes a selector as an argument, not just a dom node.

Answer (score -1):

The color coding provides a hint. You're nesting single quotes within single quotes. Wrap your php code in double quotes and things should improve:

```
$("<?php echo $form->input($r['Attribute']['label'], array('name'=>$r['Attribute']['label'],'options'=>array(1,2,3)));?>").appendTo("#main #EntrySubmit");
```

The nested single quotes are no longer ambiguous and are interpreted correctly.

Comment: if i used as u said i am getting error as
missing ) after argument list
  $("<div class="input select"><label for="Gender">Gender</label><select name="Gender" id="Gender">
<option value="0">1</option>
<option value="1">2</option>
<option value="2">3</option>
</select></div>").appendTo("#main #EntrySubmit");

Comment: the quotes inside the `<?php` and `?>` tags are evaluated separately on the server side and won't affect the javascript quotes outside it.